# Moss 2007 on windows 7 installation compatibility

Tags: windows, sharepoint-2007

Hi
I know this question shoukd not be here . i tried this on the serverfault but not responded...! an yways my issue is :

I have the machine with installed the Windows 7 Enterprise N edition. I have installed the sql server 2008 also there . so can i install MOSS 2007 on such connfiguration? if not what should i do. i tried to install but showing not compitible prompt. what have to do? is wss3.0 already present in windows 7 like windows server 2003 ? I know i can do this by virtual PC installation , but i don't want right away to virtualize machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 only installs on Windows Server operating systems from 2003 to 2008 R2.